# name is not defined in def

Tags: python, function, try-catch, except

```py
def get_token():
    token_request = requests.post(...)
    if token_request.status_code == 200:
        print('get token = OK')
    else:
        print('get token = ERROR', token_request.status_code, token_request.text)
    token = {'Authorization': ...}
...
try:
    token
except NameError:
    print('need get token')
    get_token()
    print(token)
```

output:

```
NameError: name 'token' is not defined
```

There are several ways, but this one worked for me. the variable becomes visible outside the function after it is executed, it is only executed when the "token" variable is needed by another function

```py
def get_token():
    token_request = requests.post(...)
    if token_request.status_code == 200:
        print('get token = OK')
        global token
        token = {'Authorization': ...}
    else:
        print('get token = ERROR', token_request.status_code, token_request.text)
# in other functions where i need 'token':
try:
    token
except NameError:
    print('need get token')
    get_token()
```

Comment: Show the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text (formatted as code) in the question.

Comment: `token` is a local variable of the `get_token` function and not visible outside it. You should use a `return` statement instead to return a value.

Comment: Don't catch NameError, fix your code instead.

Comment: Mandatory link to [Ned Batchelder](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html)

Comment: @MichaelButscher  i tried to be laconic, learn for future

Answer (score 0):

It makes sense to return the token inside the if (if it's ok) try this

```
def get_token():
  token_request = requests.post(...)
  if token_request.status_code == 200:
      print('get token = OK')
      token = {'Authorization': ...}
      return token
  else:
      print('get token = ERROR', token_request.status_code, 
token_request.text)
```

Comment: both suggestion make sense, thanks, but the error is still